# Show timings under same Movie Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, repeater

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        // do connection Here.
        string strShowing = "Select m.MovieName, m.Restriction, m.Language,s.StartTime   from Movie m Inner Join Schedule s ON m.MovieID=s.MovieID";

         conLoginDetails.Close();
```

How to group the time in same movie details.

Comment: Write your code in your question, not as a comment.

Comment: @Michael Then what do you want to do with the two times' values `10:00` and `13:00`? It is not logical to add them?

Comment: @Michael - Please post the desired output for the data posted in your question.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: I already post the desired output

Comment: @Michael - So you want to string concatenate them, like `10:00, 13:00` right?

Comment: ya..Because this just show the Movie Name and Time To the Customer. So How to achieved it.

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? is it SQL Server?

Comment: I am using the SQL Server to do this task. Izzit Can Use The loop to achieved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For string concatenation, AFAIK, there is no built in function do so. But you can use the [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to do so. Something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    Select m.MovieName, m.Restriction, m.Language, s.StartTime   
    from Movie m 
    Inner Join Schedule s ON m.MovieID=s.MovieID
    Where Status='Release'
)
SELECT 
  t1.MovieName,
  t1.Restriction,
  t1.Language,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.StartTime
    FROM CTE t2
    WHERE t2.MovieName = t1.MovieName
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS StartTime
FROM CTE t1
GROUP BY t1.MovieName,
         t1.Restriction,
         t1.Language;
```

Use this query instead of the query you already using:

```
string strShowing = "--put the query here--";
```

**Note that:** I used a CTE instead of writing the original query one more time in the correlated subquery.

Comment: Sir mean put the entire query from With GE...Until Group By part under the string strShowing that?

Comment: @michael - put all the query I posted in that string: `string strShowing = "WITH CTE
AS
(
    Select m.MovieName, m.Restriction, m.Language, s.StartTime   
    from Movie m 
    Inner Join Schedule s ON m.MovieID=s.MovieID
    Where Status='Release'
)
SELECT 
  t1.MovieName,
  t1.Restriction,
  t1.Language,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.StartTime
    FROM CTE t2
    WHERE t2.MovieName = t1.MovieName
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS StartTime
FROM CTE t1
GROUP BY t1.MovieName,
         t1.Restriction,
         t1.Language;";`

Comment: It is Work. Thank Mahmoud Gamal For Helping.

Comment: What is Function For CTE.

Comment: @Michael - It is called [**Common Table Expression**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: @Michael - You're welcome any time, Glad I could help :)